# OutOfMemoryException when generating a large Excel spreadsheet

Tags: asp.net, out-of-memory, npoi

I am using NPOI 1.2.3.0 in an ASP.NET application to export the results of a rather large SQL query to an Excel 2003 XLS file.

In short, the query results are populated into an ADO.NET DataTable. I then have a routine that loops through the rows in the DataTable and for each row adds a row to an NPOI spreadsheet. It is intelligent enough that once 65,000 rows are exceeded for a single sheet, a new sheet is created and the rows are continued there, starting at the first row in the new sheet.

This approach works well for some of my smaller database queries that include, say, 30,000 rows and 50 columns, but I have this one query that returns north of 125,000 rows and has roughly 50 columns, many of which have a good deal of text.

I am able to construct the spreadsheet without issue, but when I try to stream the generated spreadsheet down to the browser I get an `OutOfMemoryException` when calling the `HSSFWorkbook` class's `Write` method. (Internally, the error is happening when the Write method calls the class's `GetBytes` method.)

If I run the debugger and stop before the Write method is called, I see that the workbook's Size property returns a value of (roughly) 65 million.

This error is noted on the NPOI project at CodePlex - see the discussion titled [Out of Memory Problems](http://npoi.codeplex.com/discussions/204489) - but no resolution was found, unfortunately.

For completeness, here is the code where the exception is raised (specifically, it's raised on the `workbook.Write` line).

```
Using exportData As New MemoryStream()
    workbook.Write(exportData)

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=" & saveAsName)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.GetBuffer())
    Response.End()
End Using
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Scott - I remember reading about memory stream objects limitations in terms of capacity, which I think is 512MB in 32bit environment. Have you tried writing the Excel doc to a diiferent type of stream ?

Comment: if this does turn out to be a limitation of the memorystream itself, you could use a wrapper for the Win32 api to avoid Disk IO if you need to : eg: https://github.com/tomasr/filemap

Comment: @Dave, writing it to disk using a FileStream does *not* result in any error and successfully generates the spreadsheet. Sounds like the MemoryStream may be the culprit. The production environment is 64-bit, so I don't know if the FileMap class is the way to go.

Comment: Hi Scott  - ok, in a 64 Bit envornment the memory Stream Object will handle up to 2GB of data in Memory, so you might be ok, also, I think Framework 4 provides build in wrapper classes - I haven't looked into these, but may be worth a look - if 4.0 is an option

Comment: @Dave, 4.0 isn't an option at this time, sadly. The good news is our staging environment is 64-bit, so we can just test there. I have verified my code works with smaller Excel files and am pretty confident it works, so hopefully this is something we can test on staging to get clarification if the problem will be present there or not. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem - hope it works out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in this scenario, bearing in mind the FileStream object does not cause errors and that the error is caused by the 512MB capacity limitation in 32 bit and 2GB limitation in 64 bit, is try and write the file to the memoryStream, catch the error and revert to the FileStream for the larger files if the error is encountered.

there's an obvious performance trade off here, but if your users are downloading > 2GB files they should probably expect this to be a bit slower :-)

Would be interested to know if this works for you.

thanks,
Dave

Comment: one thing that confuses me is that the generated Excel file is about 85 MB in size. I'm unclear how an Excel document of that size would trip up the 512MB limit.

Comment: Hi Scott - thats a difficult one, and to be honest one that I am also not sure about. If I had to guess I would say it has something to do with the way the HSSPWorkbook buffers the data into the memorystream, there's likely some sort of padding going on, but without knowing the specifics of the implementation it's unclear. It may also be something to do with the COMInterop, but again I'm simply guessing here... I'm gonna have a look into it in a bit more detail when I get some time and will be sure to let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1):

NPOI doesn't only use MemoryStream but also byte array. The main root cause is the byte array. But NPOI have to use byte array so far. There is no plan to change this yet. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.